# Set key and value in angular form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

Initially i am having a simple **JSON** like this,

```
  jsonData = {
    status : "true",
    message: "Dynamic creation of input boxes and patch its value",
    result: [
        {
            "dataOneValue": "12cm"
        },
        {
            "dataTwoValue": "10cm"
        }
    ]
}
```

And `ngOnInit`,

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.jsonData.result.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
  });
```

Using this JSON, i need to create input boxes where the key and value was given in **result** array..

Using the above i need to set key and value for the input boxes,

So it will like,

key **dataOneValue** => value **12cm**

key **dataTwoValue** => value **10cm**

Here i have given only 2 just for understanding but it will not static.., It may vary based on the number of objects the result array has..

So how can i set the key and value to the input boxes from the `result` array of json?

**Stackblitz** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x7mda4

Comment: There will be only 2 text boxes ? Or you want to create as many as result has ?

Comment: @RameezRaja, It will be based on the number of object the result has and its not static of 2 boxes alone..

Comment: @undefined have updated, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6fuog

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <span *ngFor="let control of controls">
    <input type="text" [formControlName]="control" placeholder="dataOneValue">
  <br><br>
  </span>
</form>

ngOnInit() {  
  // firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  let _controls = {};
  this.jsonData.result.forEach(element => {
    let key = Object.keys(element)[0];    
    let control = [element[key], Validators.required];
    _controls[key] = control;
    this.controls.push(key);
    //console.log(_controls);
  });
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group(_controls);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work with Reactive forms by building the form dynamically:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x7mda4

In app.component.ts

```
get resultForms() {
  return this.resultForm.get('results') as FormArray
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.resultForm = this.fb.group({
    results: this.fb.array([ ]),
  });

  this.jsonData.result.forEach(element => {
    const resultGroup = this.fb.group({
      value: element[Object.keys(element)[0]]
    })
    this.resultForms.push(resultGroup);
  });
}
```

In app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="resultForm">
  <div formArrayName="results">
      <div *ngFor="let result of resultForms.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input formControlName="value">
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```